# Can embedding_rnn_seq2seq function return all states?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am playing Seq2Seq model use embedding_rnn_seq2seq function ,
i read document say embedding_rnn_seq2seq return outputs and state that in each time-step ,
but i try to get state only can get one step

here is my model

```
seq_length = 100
batch_size = 128
vocab_size = 12
memory_dim = 100

enc_inp = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,), name="inp%i" % t)  for t in range(seq_length)]
labels = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,), name="labels%i" % t)   for t in range(seq_length)]

dec_inp = ([tf.zeros_like(labels[0], dtype=np.int32, name="GO")] + labels[:-1])
weights = [tf.ones_like(labels_t, dtype=tf.float32) for labels_t in labels]

cell = rnn_cell.GRUCell(memory_dim)
dec_outputs, dec_memory = seq2seq.embedding_rnn_seq2seq(enc_inp,dec_inp,cell,vocab_size,vocab_size,vocab_size)

loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss(dec_outputs, labels, weights, vocab_size)
```

try to get state (dec_memory)

```
dec_memory_batch = sess.run(dec_memory , feed_dict)
```

only return a one-step memory_dim size vector , maybe is last step state
So , do anyone have some advice ?